# Is This a Bet or a Raise?

Tags: poker-theory, cash-game, terminology

Assuming more than 3 players at the table in no limit game.

SB and BB just places blinds.
Next to act is UTG1.

Which of the following options is terminologically correct?

1. Call, **Bet**, Allin, Fold
2. Call, **Raise**, Allin, Fold

And why?

Comment: Not sure if this even makes sense?! Are we talking game mechanics, or strategy? Care to elaborate?

Comment: If you can't add more details to this soon, I'm inclined to close it. I hope you can.

Comment: I guess the question is: If UTG1 bets more than a BB, is this called *bet* or *raise*?

Comment: This is question about common terminology. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good answer. It depends on the poker room's terminology.

Sometimes the first `bet` is called a `raise`, because the blinds are referred as bets.

In other rooms there is always one `bet` before any `raise`.

For more info about terms, see the [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_poker_terms) page.

Comment: UTG is a raise (after the blinds) according to full tilt

Answer (score 3):

Although you are betting chips when you make a raise, it is more common to call any increase of a non-zero bet a "raise," not a "bet." (If you verbalized your action, it would be more felicitous to say "I raise to 25," not "I bet 25.")

Note that in some corners of the poker universe, one distinguishes between **opens** and **raises**. There, the correct options might be listed as fold, call, and **open**. This is not merely terminological: different rules can govern opens and raises. (E.g.: sometimes raising an open requires doubling the entire amount of the open, whereas reraising a raise requires only increasing the bet by the amount of the raise. So: in rooms where you **raise** a $5 blind to $25, the minimum reraise is to $45; but in certain games where you rather **open** to $25, the minimum (re)raise would be to $50.)

Comment: A raise from $5 to $25 would be a $20 raise, so wouldn't the minimum re-raise be $45 instead of $40?  +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

The big blind has BET. True, t's a FORCED bet that leads to his being called the "blind." (He made his bet without seeing his cards. Actually, the small blind is in for half a bet, so the big blind "raises" the small blind.)

If the under the gun playermatches the "blind's" bet, s/he CALLS. If the under the gun player increases the Blind's bet, s/he raises.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand the question here.

They will have the same options that they have in any position... Call, Bet, All In or Fold. Bet and Raise are the same thing really. So as gkovacs90 says it depends on the terminology of the poker room itself.

But they will have the same choices regardless of their position. Unless it has been raised before them. In which case the answer is number 2.